# Sum over primes in a paper of Selberg

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

[image]

The above is from paper of Selberg on the elementary proof of prime number theorem. Prior to eq.$(2.11)$ the author derives an asymptotic expression for $\sum_{pq≤x}\ln(p)\ln(q)$, where $p,q$ are primes. For that he makes use of eq.$(2.10)$.

In eq.$(2.10)$ the remainder term is $O\left(\frac{x}{\ln(x)}\right)$. So using it for $\sum_{pq≤x}\ln(p)\ln(q)$ should result in the remainder term $O\left(\frac{x/p}{\ln(x/p)}\right)$

**My question:-**

(1) Why did the author take the remainder term to be $O\left(\frac{x/p}{1+\ln(x/p)}\right)$?

(2) How does that become $O(x\ln\ln(x))$ by using abel summation?

Comment: When $x=p$, $\ln(x/p)=0$ and you do not want to divide by $0$.

Comment: @Gary, I understand that but I don't see how does that adds 1 to the denominator of the remainder term. Another small hint to see that is helpful

Comment: Note that $$O\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\ln x}}} \right) = O\!\left( {\frac{x}{{1 + \ln x}}} \right),$$ and the later is useful if $x=1$ can happen, because $1+\ln x = 1>0$ in that case.

Comment: Okay, now I see! But what about my second question? Should I perform the abel summation using $\sum_{p≤x}\ln(p)=O(x)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments,

$$O\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\ln x}}} \right) = O\!\left( {\frac{x}{{1 + \ln x}}} \right).$$

The reason why we the author adds $1$ is because the term when $p = x$ is in the sum and $\log(x/p)$ would be $0$ — and we don't want to divide by zero.

The second question concerns showing
$$
x \sum_{p \leq x} \frac{\log p}{p (1 + \log x/p)}
\ll
x \log \log x.
$$
For this, we convert to a Riemann-Stieltjes integration problem (approximately equivalent to summation by parts or Abel summation).
For this it will be convenient to note that the derivative
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\log t}{t (1 + \log x/t)}
=
-\frac{\log\left(t\right)}{t^{2} {\left(\log\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) + 1\right)}} + \frac{1}{t^{2} {\left(\log\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) + 1\right)}} + \frac{\log\left(t\right)}{t^{2} {\left(\log\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) + 1\right)}^{2}}
\approx
-\frac{\log\left(t\right)}{t^{2} {\left(\log\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) + 1\right)}}.
$$
Then we have by integration by parts
$$ \sum_{p \leq x} \frac{\log p}{p (1 + \log x/p)}
= \int_{2}^x \frac{\log t}{t (1 + \log x/t)} d \lfloor \pi(t) \rfloor
\lesssim
\frac{\log x}{x} \pi(x) - \frac{\log 2}{2} + \int_2^x \pi(t) \frac{\log\left(t\right)}{t^{2} {\left(\log\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) + 1\right)}} dt.
$$
This would be a pure equality if I used the whole derivative above, but I extract the dominant contribution here and write $\lesssim$ instead. (Note this includes the only *positive* contribution). The first term

By the prime number theorem, $\pi(t) \sim t\log t$. Thus
\begin{align}
\int_2^x \pi(t) \frac{\log\left(t\right)}{t^{2} {\left(\log\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) + 1\right)}} dt
&\ll
\int_2^x \frac{t}{\log t} \frac{\log\left(t\right)}{t^{2} {\left(\log\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) + 1\right)}} dt
=
\int_2^x \frac{1}{t {\left(\log\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) + 1\right)}} dt
\\
&\ll
\int_2^{x-3} \frac{1}{t {\left(\log\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)\right)}} dt
=
- \log \log (x/t) \Big|_{2}^{x-3} \ll \log \log (x/2) \ll \log \log x.
\end{align}
I use the final bound $x-3$ above for a similar reason that Selberg uses $1 + \ln x$ — it makes the domain of the log work out (and the final bit of the integral is much smaller than the rest, so we lose nothing).